# Basic Objective C grammar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am learning iOS development. In a setter method, I do not know the grammar and its function.

```
-(void)setURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
  _URL = URL;
  if(_URL) {
     NSURLRequest *req = NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_URL];
     [(UIWebView *)self.view loadRequest:req];
      }
}
```

All I don't understand is that line:

```
[(UIWebView *)self.view loadRequest:req];
```

It is my first time to meet that situation:indicate self as a pointer to a UIWebView instance? or indicate self.view as a pointer to a UIWebView instance? If the latter, it quite makes sense. In my application, self is a instance of UIViewController, and its view property is a UIWebView. But what is the point to add it? Why not just use self.view instead? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's manually telling the compiler that `self.view` is of type `UIWebView *` – this is known as typecasting.  `UIViewController`'s `view` property is defined to be `UIView *`.  This class doesn't have any method `loadRequest:`, so if you try to call it without casting the object to `UIWebView *`, then the compiler will warn you that you appear to be doing something incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is clear and easy understanding. With another answer, I have fully understood the question! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

When you see an expression that performs several operations with no explicit order, it is a good idea to check with the [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The `(UIWebView *)self.view` component has two operations - dot `.` operator, and a type cast. According to the table, dot operator has the highest precedence, so `self.view` is evaluated first. Type cast has lower precedence, so the result of `self.view` is cast to `(UIWebView*)` prior to making the call.

Comment: Thank you very much. It extends my knowledge quite a lot. And it definitely will help me a lot in future programming life.Thank you again!